# Set visibility TableLayout based item selected on Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I want to make Spinner to set Visibility of table, i have 2 Array String "cuboid and cylinder". if i select Cuboid , cubeT table is visible and cyclinderT table is Invisible. and if i select Cylinder , cylinderT table is Visible and cubeT is Invisible.

Sample code welcome. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an OnItemSelectedListener to your Spinner then using the `int position` argument to decide what action to take.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case Cuboid: 
                       cubeT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       cylinderT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                    ....
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) { }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String text = ((Spinner)spinner).getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (Intrinsics.areEqual(text, "Cuboid")) {
            //Your code here to set your "table" as cubeT if it's image in imageview
            //if it's a "tableLayout" you may create 2 different layouts included and..:
            setContentView(R.layout.your_cubeT_layout);         
        } else if (Intrinsics.areEqual(text, "Cylinder")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.your_cyclinderT_layout);
          }
    } //when it comes to use different layouts on the same activity, generally suggestions made over fragments to make your code more dynamic but i don't know how to do that...

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

I'm not using java since years so i might code bad... So no warranty!